# Do $LC$ tank oscillators violate the conservation of linear momentum?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, mass, harmonic-oscillator

### General setup

Consider the following thought experiment: A capacitor $C$ and an inductor $L$ are mounted with fixed joints on a plate in outer space at say $1$ meter apart. They are connected in the $LC$ harmonic oscillator configuration. When powered the energy is exchanged between one to the other one. The sum of the energies on both remains constant over time.

One can eventually even drop the existence of the plate and just assume that the capacitor and the inductor are at a fixed $1$ meter distance apart.

### Question

Using the mass energy equivalence formula $E = m\cdot c^2$ follows that the mass of $C$ varies with the energy of the capacitor as well as the mass of L varies with the energy of the inductor. Is therefore the center of gravity of the assembly moving in time (oscillating) without any external force being acted on it? **Does this violate the law of the conservation of linear momentum?**

Comment: What a nice paradox! Put simply, mass shuffles backwards and forwards at a finite speed from C to L and vice versa, implying momentum first in one direction then in the other and so on. I'm wondering about whether we should consider the momentum of the photons emitted by accelerating charges in the wires, but there's probably something much simpler than that going on!

Comment: @PhilipWood I am not quite sure if this is or not sarcastic, but assuming is not, I do not think that photons/anything are/is being emitted because in such a case the movement would need to eventually stop (or "something" should be also received), right?! This is not the case in the presented experiment, is it not ?!

Comment: No sarcasm intended – desperation, perhaps. There certainly will be photons emitted, because we have accelerating charges, though the effect will be very small (because the accelerations are so small). But then the mass transfer is also very small. But as I've said, I expect that your paradox has a simpler resolution!

Comment: Your post does not give _any_ expression for momentum, nor its conservation or otherwise.  That should be your first objective; show us a non-constant expression for the momentum!

Comment: @m4r35n357 Ok, I am just saying that the center of mass of an object is being shifted periodically. I am not implying that there is any momentum involved. I do not know how to explain this. I just thought that a shifting center is always a result of an external linear momentum transfer. I think this is a counter example ...

Comment: @PhilipWood The mass transfer can be arbitrarily large (at least theoretically). The energy is not being transferred through wires but through the so called Poynting vector ?!? The accelerated charges you are mentioning are in both directions (hence should cancel out) and are very small, since we are talking about the drift velocities right?

Comment: @C Marius I agree with your last comment, though I'm not sure about the cancelling out.

Comment: @PhilipWood So (assuming zero wires resistance) you are implying that is possible that the LC oscillator emits photons left and right for ever? Wouldn't this lead to the conclusion that the energy in the LC circuit must vanish in time?

Comment: @m4r35n357 For the little it's worth I make the maximum momentum in the system due to the mass transfer $$p_{max} =\frac{l\  Q_0^2}{2 c^2 \sqrt{LC^3}}$$ in which $l$ is the distance between L and C.

Comment: @Marius I'm implying that energy will be emitted as radiation, so that the oscillations will be damped, even in the absence of resistive damping. That's alright isn't it? But, like you, I'm worried about the symmetry of charge movement.

Comment: @PhilipWood I thought that the oscillations in the "perfect" LC circuit are not damped in time, but most of my knowledge comes from electronics rather than physics. And, yes, analyzing the movement of electrons in the circuit it seems to me that as many as leave one end of the capacitor should enter the other lead. Or can it be otherwise ?

Comment: "I thought that the oscillations in the "perfect" LC circuit are not damped in time". I'm not sure that we can have such perfection. Admittedly the emitted energy is usually negligible for oscillations at audio frequency, but remember that Hertz's source of e-m waves was an LC circuit (admittedly operating at about 50 MHz and with an 'open plate' capacitor).

Comment: @m4r35n357 A neater and more instructive version of my earlier formula is simply $$p_{\text{max}}=\frac{l \omega}{c^2} U_\text{max}$$ in which $l$ is the distance between L and C and $U_\text{max}$ is the maximum energy stored in the inductor or capacitor.

Comment: What makes you think that the center of mass is moving?

Comment: @nasu Well, I observed that at one instance C is heavier, then L is heavier (according to the energy they have). In order to have the COM stationary one would have to assume that the physical circuit is moving left and right. This is something I thought is not happening since this movement would "consume" the energy in the circuit and I thought that the LC oscillates undamped.

Comment: The fact that they exchange mass (if they do) does not mean that the center of mass moves. And the motion of the circuit does not imply dissipation of energy. You make some unsupported assumptions.  What about two people in a boat throwing a ball back and forth? Is this a violation of conservation of momentum?

Comment: @nasu 1)  If L and C exchange mass then the physical circuit should also move such that the center of gravity is not moving. I thought the physical circuit is NOT moving hence I concluded that the center of mass is moving. 2) Why I thought that the physical circuit is NOT moving? Because in such a situation, I thought, as two people in a boat, the LC oscillator would consume energy, a thing I thought that the LC oscillator does not. I basically thought that accelerating and decelerating the physical circuit consumes the energy from the tank oscillator, from where else?!  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes,  I suppose the energy may be dissipated.  Nothing wrong with this. Why would you assume that is not?

Comment: Because in such a case the LC would eventually stop oscillating and (from circuit theory) I considered that to be false. But right now, even if the energy is indeed dissipating through radiation I cannot figure out why is not equally in all directions. I do not see right now the momentum generating mechanism

Answer (score 1):

> Is therefore the center of gravity of the assembly moving in time (oscillating) without any external force being acted on it? Does this violate the law of the conservation of linear momentum?

Not even remotely. Circuit theory is an approximation of Maxwell’s equations. It is intrinsically non-relativistic, so using circuit theory in the context of relativity is inherently problematic. On the one hand you are ignoring relativity while on the other you are not. You are essentially guaranteed to get nonsensical results.

To do this properly you would need to use Maxwell’s equations, which are fully relativistic. If you analyze the circuit using Maxwell’s equations then you will find momentum is conserved. This has been proven in general, not merely for your specific case, by Poynting’s theorem.

Comment: So, the logical conclusion is that the physical circuit is moving left and right such that the COM is stationary. This movement I imagine consumes the energy in the LC oscillator which will eventually stop oscillating. Is this what happens ? The LC tank circuit can never be undamped !?

Comment: Does relativity theory allow undamped LC oscillators?

Comment: I don’t think that special relativity would forbid undamped oscillations, but Maxwell’s equations do. The circuit will radiate

Comment: I am having difficulties in understanding for this specific case how the Poynting vector shows that the C component should experience a linear moment when discharging/ charging. Looking at the $S = \frac{1}{\mu_0} E \times H$ this will be symmetrically orthogonal on the wires and C. So, yes, it might radiate, but why does not radiate equally in all directions?

Comment: The easiest way to see this is to write Poynting’s theorem in fully relativistic form: $\partial_\nu T^{\mu \nu}+f^\mu =0$, where $T$ is the EM field stress energy tensor, which includes energy density, Poynting vector, and EM stress, and $f$ is the Lorentz power and force density on matter. So any energy and momentum that leaves the field goes to matter and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

It is a  theorem in relativity that the centre of "mass" defined by
$$
{\mathcal  E}X^\mu_{\rm cofm} = \int T^{00}(x) x^\mu \sqrt{g}d^3x
$$
does not move for  isolated system with total momentum zero. Here $T^{00}$ is the energy density and ${\mathcal E}$ the total energy
$$
{\mathcal E}= \int T^{00}(x)  \sqrt{g}d^3x
$$

Despite this theorem there are many appararent paradoxes that come from combining *non-relativistic* mechanics with the fully relativistic Maxwell equations. They are  resolved when you realize the the field momentum density
$$
{\bf p}=\frac 1{c^2} {\bf E}\times {\bf H}
$$
having $1/c^2$ factor means that one has to keep $1/c^2$ relativistic corrections to the mechanics.  The general heading for these effects is [hidden momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_momentum).

Comment: By looking at the Poynting vector $S=\frac{1}{\mu_0} E \times H$ (collinear with $p$) we get that the energy always flow into the wires symmetrically. Moreover. for instance, for the case when the capacitor is discharging, it loses energy to inductor (so it should move to left, assuming L is to the right, to keep the COM in place), but computing the Poynting vector the energy flows radially/symmetrically out of and orthogonally on the capacitor. Therefore, I still do not get practically why the capacitor is moving! Those moments should be symmetrical!

Comment: Energy is moving about, some of it in the energy of the electromagnetic field and so of it in the $mc^2$'s  of the coil and capacitor. The center of *energy* stays put, so the tank cicuit will jiggle (impercepably) from side to side.

Comment: Or it will radiate energy in one side then to the other ... the center of energy includes the energy lost to the radiation right?

Answer (score 0):

When capacitor shoots energy to the right, then capacitor recoils to the left.

Comment: How can I observe that? By looking at the Poynting vector $S = \frac{1}{\mu+0}E \times B$ we get that the energy always flow into the wires. Moreover, the energy flow and the current flow can never be in the same direction. The energy flow is always perpendicular on the electric field. For instance, for the case when the capacitor is discharging, it loses energy, but computing the Poynting vector the energy flows radially/symmetrically out of and orthogonally on the capacitor. Am I wrong?

Comment: @CMarius OK. If capacitor emits energy to all directions, then it's the wires that direct that energy to where the wires lead. And the wires experience the recoil.  Hmm yes, if we have a plate capacitor and we  start discharging it from the middle of the plates, then the the plates do not recoil.

Comment: As I said, the energy flows into the wires and, from what I can imagine, there is no net momentum applied to them because of this.

Comment: @C Marius   Capacitor shoots energy to two wires that are left to the capacitor. Capacitor recoils to the right. Capacitor shoots energy to two wires, that are left to the capacitor and right to the capacitor. Capacitor does not recoil, energy has no net momentum.  If we want to connect those wires to a inductor, we must bend the wires, the energy pushes the wire where the bend is, centrifugal force.

Comment: @CMarius If flowing energy manages to move the wire then the wire gains energy and energy loses energy. If the motion is transmissed to another wire then that wire may do work on the energy flowing inside of it. This is some kind of  answer to your energy problem that I spotted in the comments.